# For loop to assign value to variable based on value of another var

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Yes, Hello coders

I'm tring to assign value to the variable within the data frame based on another variable
my data looks like:

```
Housing_ID   Member_ID     My_new_staus
 1            1
 1            2
 1            3
 1            4
 1            5
 2            1
 2            2
 3            1
 3            2
 3            3
```

what i want to assign is where the housing id equals to 1 (which is repeated) put the My_new_staus: "Valid"

I tried to apply it through this code:

```
for i in range (len(df['Housing_ID'])):
if df['Housing_ID'][i] ==  1 :
    df['My_new_staus'][i] = 'Valid'
else: 
    df['My_new_staus'][i] = ''
```

and got this message : # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
KeyError: 398

the output that i want is

```
Housing_ID   Member_ID     My_new_staus
 1            1            Valid
 1            2            Valid
 1            3            Valid
 1            4            Valid
 1            5            Valid
 2            1
 2            2
 3            1
 3            2
 3            3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to assign values to `'My_new_status'`:

```
df['My_new_status'] = np.where(df['Housing_ID']==1,'valid','')
```

Output:

```
   Housing_ID  Member_ID My_new_status
0           1          1        valid
1           1          2        valid
2           1          3        valid
3           1          4        valid
4           1          5        valid
5           2          1             
6           2          2             
7           3          1             
8           3          2             
9           3          3
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid iterating through dataframes. You can just use an [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = \
df.assign(My_new_status = df.Member_ID.apply(lambda row: 'Valid' if x==1 else ''))
```